# How content assist works in Eclipse and how to mimic that functionality for my application

Tags: java, eclipse

Can somebody help me on how content assist works in eclipse and how I mimic that functionality for my desktop java application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is built on SWT and JFace, in other words, it's part of the UI toolkit Eclipse interface is based on. Since you have a average desktop application I assume your program's GUI is Swing and I don't know about content proposals in the Swing toolkit.

Some links on the Eclipse Platform (<- overall name for technologies like SWT, JFace, more general plugin development):

- [Eclipse Wiki: JFace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace)
- [Eclipse Wiki: JFace UI Framework -> Field Assist](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjface.htm)